# Docker permission errors on Ubuntu Core

Tags: permissions, docker, ubuntu-core

After installing Docker Snap on Ubuntu Core I can build and run Docker containers.  However, I'm forced to use **sudo** for all the Docker commands, otherwise I get the following error:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ docker ps
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
user@ubuntu:~$
```

I found some instructions on here how to get around it, but they will not work on Ubuntu Core:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socket

When I follow the instructions I get the following error:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo groupadd docker
groupadd: cannot lock /etc/group; try again later.
user@ubuntu:~$
```

[image]

I am assuming that since I am running on Ubuntu Core, which is a immutable 'container' operating system it will be impossible for me to add groups or modify permissions.

Can someone verify this?

Comment: What's the rationale for using Ubuntu Core rather than Ubuntu Server?

Comment: This is what I am trying to decide on now "Ubuntu Server" versus "Ubuntu Core".  Whether to run Snaps on Ubuntu Core or use Docker and generally which approach to take.

Comment: Core is great for deploying a snap-only solution which has already been proven to work on Ubuntu Server in development. I wouldn't use it as a first choice, unless you've proven everything works snap-only on an Ubuntu server, personally.

Comment: Did you add `user` to the `docker` group? That would be required on a regular Docker install. (I have no experience with Ubuntu Core or the Docker snap, so no idea if things are different there.)

Comment: Yes, I have tried that.  The first thing that must be done is to create the Docker group, but I cannot do that because there is a lock on /etc/group at all times in Ubuntu Core.  

After that run `sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}`  , but I get an error `usermod: group docker does not exist`.  Hence, need to create the group.